# automated opening of an external link

Tags: html, flash

I have a flash intro for my website and I want after the flash is finished to automatically open an external link,
how can I make this?
This is the index.html:

```
script>
        swfobject.embedSWF('main.swf', 'intro', '100%', '100%', '9','js/expressinstall.swf', {XMLSource:'intro.xml', domain: '*'}, {allowfullscreen: "true", allowscriptaccess: 'always',  bgcolor: '#ffffff', menu: 'false'}, {id: 'intro'});

    </script>

</head>

<body style="margin:0px;overflow:hidden"> 

<div id="intro">
        <p>In order to view this page you need Flash Player 9+ support!</p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: you should do this with ActionScript, not with the HTML wrapper.  instead of hardcoding the website in ActionScript, you should call a JavaScript function using ExternalInterface that will open the link so updating the link will not require republishing of your swf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a meta refresh and set the length of time to the length of the swf file -

http://www.web-source.net/html_redirect.htm

But never use a flash intro page :)